# What's the difference between setVar and Magic setter in phalcon Controllers

Tags: php, phalcon

Reading the documentation of phalcon https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/views.html I found that it's possible to pass variables from the controller to the view in 2 different ways:

1. Using setVar()

   ```
   $this->view->setVar("username", $user->username);
   $this->view->setVar("posts",    $posts;
   ```
2. Using the magic setter

   ```
   $this->view->username = $user->username;
   $this->view->posts    = $posts;
   ```

What's the difference between the two and what is the magic setter really, I couldn't find what it is.

Comment: there is no difference, both do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy, what's the magic setter then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only difference is return value.

Method setVar return $this, magic setter return void.

Check this:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/view.zep#L1373
and compare with this: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/view.zep#L450

Comment: Thanks @pwoszczyk, so, which one should I use?

Comment: It depends only of code format which you like. I prefer magic setter.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is performance. Better to use `setVar` method. Of course in real world the difference will be none with setting two variables.

Comment: Thanks @Juri, where did you find documentation for that? I couldn't find anything... or did you actually run some tests?

Comment: I just runned some tests. It will be similar difference than in plain php, one 10 iterations calling method itself was to 3 times faster than using magic property. But it was something like 0.4 second to 0.13 second so on few variable setting just forget about this and use whatever you want.